# Why is Google Tag Manager free?

Tags: google, google-tag-manager

So I was wondering today why Google Tag Manager is free. Nothing is free in this world so I was trying to think what the benefit is to Google for having the service?
With their other products I can imagine many reasons to provide the services but not so much with GTM?

- Search Console - Improve your website and therefore provide a better experience
   for users on Google.
- AdWords - Duh
- Analytics - Improve your website and therefore provide a better experience for users on Google. Also provide bench marking data for Google and probably other useful data
- Gmail - Comb through your email and serve you ads. Probably more.

What do you think?

Comment: There is [enterprise version](https://www.google.com/analytics/tag-manager/compare/) of it which provide more functionality. Google does not use google analytics data for search but they can produce similar analytics reports to get user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL:DR - It's freemium.

There's some false assumptions there - for example, Analytics (originally Urchin) has a premium version that can cost anywhere from $45k a year or up. The free version is just advertising for that.

The same goes for Google Tag Manager and other Google products like Data studio or Optimizely. There is a premium version with expanded functionality beyond the 'free' version. If your company becomes reliant on the free version then it's very likely once you have the budget and need for something more, upgrading the environment you're currently developing in is the best choice.